# Does an argument after a redirection do anything?

Tags: linux, bash, redirect

Is any argument after a redirection ignored, or does it have any unintended consequences?

I was surprised to find that a typo I made in my bash script made absolutely no difference because it was specified after a redirect. E.g. I expected it to complain about something like this

```
./foo.sh > foo2.log whoops I made a typo
```

But it doesn't throw any errors. I have to add a semi colon to actually get it to run as a command and error, something like

```
./foo.sh > foo2.log; whoops I made a typo
```

What surprised me even more, is that linux hasn't given up after the redirect
e.g.

```
./foo.sh > foo2.log whoops I made a typo > command_is_still_going.log
```

is absolutely fine and command_is_still_going.log is still created

Is the 'whoops I made a typo' argument completely ignored, or does it result in some unwanted behaviour? Since I tend to use this a lot.

Comment: Dive into the [documentation of bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/). Doing what you suggest is bad taste,  so people never do that in practice

Comment: This seems like an easy question to answer. If you run `echo one > log two three`, what is the resulting content of the `log` file? Were the additional arguments ignored, or not?

Comment: thanks @larsks realised that after I posted. So looks like the answer is yes, if your bash script refers to input arguments this could well cause unexpected things to happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redirections are parsed and handled, then removed from the command-line. The remaining command-line is then executed. In other words, redirections can appear anywhere in the command-line. As a point of style you should put them at the end.

These are equivalent:

```
./foo.sh > foo2.log whoops I made a typo
./foo.sh whoops I made a typo > foo2.log
```

If `foo.sh` ignores its arguments then "whoops I made a typo" has no effect.

Similarly, these are the same:

```
./foo.sh > foo2.log whoops I made a typo > command_is_still_going.log
./foo.sh whoops I made a typo > foo2.log > command_is_still_going.log
```

These are two separate commands:

```
./foo.sh > foo2.log; whoops I made a typo

./foo.sh > foo2.log
whoops I made a typo
```

Comment: For completeness, be aware that a redirection can also appear *before* a simple command (`> foo2.log ./foo.sh whoops I made a typo`), but not before a compound command (`> foo2.log for x in 1 2 3; do echo "$x"; done` is not valid.)

Answer (score 1):

You could run:

```
> set -x
> ./foo.sh > foo2.log whoops I made a typo
```

And you could see what was actually run:

```
> + ./foo.sh whoops I made a typo
```

As shown above, the extra text was passed as arguments to foo.sh.

Answer (score 0):

OK i think I have my answer. Direct in linux you can do things like
`echo 'whoops' > foo.log I made a typo`
and that will output to screen 'whoops I made a typo'

So essentially the redirect is just be stripped out of the processing of the line, and so the unintended result would be anything after the redirect is processed as an argument to the bash script.

Proved this out by making foo.sh simply `echo $1`. Then running it as
`./foo.sh > foo.log whatever` logs 'whatever' as the first argument